# Correct gstreamer pipeline for particular rtsp stream

Tags: mp4, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to convert this RTSP URL to something else (anything!) using this gst pipeline:

```
gst-launch rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov ! rtpmp4vdepay ! filesink location=somebytes.bin
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2791): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
```

So I guess it's something about connecting the rstp source to the depayloader. If I change the pipeline to use rtpmp4gdepay rather than vdepay, it works and produces *something*, but I'm not sure what the output format is.

Does anyone know what pipeline I should be using to get at the video from this URL? I'm assuming it's mp4/h264/aac, but maybe it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this first:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v playbin2 uri=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
```

Answer (score 1):

Mov file is not directly streamable. So your RTSP source is probably sending you two elementary streams. (I am guessing this is darwin or some other similar server) So you may have to setup two outputs from rtspsrc one for audio and one for video.

rtpmp4vpay is for elementary mpeg4 streams. Is your source file having mpeg4 video codec?  If it is h.264 replace it with rtph264depay. you can pass the output to decoder and play it if you want. Feed it to decodebin. To dump it in h.264 you will first have to parse and add nal headers to it ( h264parse parse perhaps? )

rtpmp4gpay is most probably accepted for the audio stream.

I am guessing your file is h.264/aac which is why rtpmp4vdepay wont work and rtpmp4gdepay will. But you are not doing anything about the video when you setup rtpmp4gdepay so you need to do that.